# Flyspell save word to dictionary

Tags: emacs, auctex

I'm using flyspell for spell checking in AucTeX.

How can I ignore or add a word to the dictionary *without* using the popup menu and without using the mouse?

There's the command `flyspell-auto-correct-word` (<kbd>C-.</kbd>) to go through all suggestions for corrections, is there also a command for saing words to the dictionary?

Comment: Since this is about spell checking in Emacs in general and not spell checking in Emacs specifically related to TeX this question is more on topic on Stack Overflow or Super User. I have flagged it for migration to either.

Answer (score 21):

You can ask for the completion with <kbd>M-$</kbd> and add a word with
<kbd>i</kbd> (it'll ask before saving it). Use <kbd>?</kbd> to see all
options available.